# Addition Python Function

Tags: python

So I have to create a program that asks the user 5 addition questions and they can type the right answer. I am very new at python and functions in general so helpful answers only please. I know how to get random numbers and make it so the question for ex: "What is 4 + 5?" I just do not know how to ask 5 different addition questions within the function. This is what I have.

```
import random
def add():
    num1=random.randint(1,10)
    num2=random.randint(1,10)
    return num1,num2



def main():
    x,y= add()
    plus=int(input("What is {} + {} ?".format(x,y)))



main()
```

Comment: When asking about errors, it is important to describe exactly what the error was... please edit your question to add this detail

Comment: Not true, there is no error, at least in Python2.7. Please precise which interpreter version are you using.

Comment: @Nsh: reading the question, there is error, the OP simply doesn't now how to implement the remaining specs.

Comment: I went back and now there is no error but I am unsure how to make it continue to ask an addition question even if the answer given by the user is right or wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get an error when I run your code. Here is an answer for you:

Right now your main() is asking for an input back from the user and each time main() is called it will ask for a different number, so if you like you can do something like this:

```
for _ in range(5):
    main()
```

But from the sound of it, you want to have the function main() ask all of the questions, namely - something like this:

```
def main():
    for _ in range(5):
        x,y = add()
        plus = int(input("What is {} + {} ?".format(x,y)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `for loop` to ask the user 5 times

```
def main():
    for i in range(5):
         x,y = add()
         plus = int(input("What is {} + {} ?".format(x,y)))
```

To check if the answer is correct just you can do:

```
 if x + y == plus: print "good"
 else: print "bad"
```

Comment: How would I tell the user of whatever answer they put is right or wrong , and if wrong show the correct answer?

Comment: Since it is randomly generated I am confused how to tell the computer to show the right answer if the user inputed the wrong one.

Comment: Just have `x+y` compare to `plus`, `if x+y == plus: "correct"`

Answer (score 0):

Simplest is to use a counting loop:

```
def main():

    for i in range(5):
         x,y = add()
         plus = int(input("What is {} + {} ?".format(x,y)))
```

Comment: what if I want to tell them the right answer if their answer was incorrect??

Comment: @SydneyFranklin: that was not in the original question, and you have already accepted a correct answer.  Surely you can figure out a simple `if` statement yourself?  If not, then ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

The following program demonstrates how to have a program ask five addition questions:

```
import random
import sys

def main():
    for count in range(5):
        ask_addition_question()

def ask_addition_question():
    numbers = random.randrange(10), random.randrange(10)
    answer = get_number('What is {} + {}? '.format(*numbers))
    total = sum(numbers)
    if answer == total:
        print('That is correct!')
    else:
        print('Actually, the correct answer is {}.'.format(total))

def get_number(query):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(query))
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('Please try again.')
        except EOFError:
            sys.exit()
        except ValueError:
            print('You must enter a number.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```